# how to restrict use to browse correct locale using ActionFilter or middleware

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

Aim: I have a url like http://localhost:55830/us/product and it's working fine. But i want to restrict user to browse http://localhost:55830/en-us/product and if user try to browse this , then I want to redirect him/her to http://localhost:55830/us/product. How can i do this using Middleware or can i achieve this using ActionFilter?

Comment: Read up on this [URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: I tried using adding below code but it does not working:

 



 `app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()      
         .AddRedirect("^([^/]*)/en-us/(.*)$", "{R:1}/us/{R:2}", 
  (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently));`

Comment: You should update the question with what you tried and is not working. making reference to the article that you are following.

Comment: I tried with above code but this is not working. looking for expert advice here.